# React Native - Tradução das funções de longPress IOS - Paste, Autofill

Tags: react-native

Tenho uma aplicação ReactNAtive e em um campo input no IOS, quando pressionamos para colar algo, aparece um tooltip mas o problema é que na aplicação as opções de colar, autocompletar aparecem em ingles mesmo o celular estando com o idioma Português Brasil. Fora do app as opções aparecem em português mas no app em si aparece em inglês.[Print no meu app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxgaY.png) e [Print fora do app em notas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRiXU.png)

Alguém poderia me ajudar a conseguir deixar isso em português no RN ?